# ag-grid-react editor component not working MoodCellRenderer

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to dynamically edit the cell value but some of the components are not working properly like `MoodCellRenderer` and `NumericCellEditor`. Other editor components are working fine.
Can you please help me to make it work?

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {AgGridReact} from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';

function cloneObject(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}


class Example8 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [{
          headerName: "Value",
          field: "value",
          width: 100,
          editable: true,
          cellEditorSelector: function(params) {
            if (params.data.type === 'age') return {
              component: 'numericCellEditor'
            };

            if (params.data.type === 'gender') return {
              component: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
              params: {
                values: ['Male', 'Female']
              }
            };

            if (params.data.type === 'mood') return {
              component: 'moodEditor'
            };

            return null;
          }
        },
        {
          headerName: "Type",
          field: "type",
          width: 100
        }
      ],

      rowData: [{
          value: 14,
          type: 'age'
        },
        {
          value: 'female',
          type: 'gender'
        },
        {
          value: "Happy",
          type: 'mood'
        },
        {
          value: 21,
          type: 'age'
        },
        {
          value: 'male',
          type: 'gender'
        },
        {
          value: "Sad",
          type: 'mood'
        }
      ],
      gridOptions: {

        onRowEditingStarted: function(event) {
          console.log('never called - not doing row editing');
        },
        onRowEditingStopped: function(event) {
          console.log('never called - not doing row editing');
        },
        onCellEditingStarted: function(event) {
          console.log('cellEditingStarted');
        },
        onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
          console.log('cellEditingStopped');
        },
        components: {
          genderCellRenderer: GenderCellRenderer,
          numericCellEditor: NumericCellEditor,
          moodCellRenderer: MoodCellRenderer,
          moodEditor: MoodEditor,
          countryCellRenderer: CountryCellRenderer
        }
      }
    };
  }

  onGridReady = params => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            id="myGrid"
            style={{
              height: "100%",
              width: "100%"
            }}
            className="ag-theme-balham"
          >
            <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
              components={this.state.components}
              rowData={this.state.rowData}
              onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}


function getCharCodeFromEvent(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  return (typeof event.which == "undefined") ? event.keyCode : event.which;
}

function isCharNumeric(charStr) {
  return !!/\d/.test(charStr);
}

function isKeyPressedNumeric(event) {
  var charCode = getCharCodeFromEvent(event);
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  return isCharNumeric(charStr);
}

// simple function cellRenderer, just returns back the name of the country
function CountryCellRenderer(params) {
  return params.value.name;
}

// function to act as a class
function NumericCellEditor() {}

// gets called once before the renderer is used
NumericCellEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
  // create the cell
  this.eInput = document.createElement('input');

  if (isCharNumeric(params.charPress)) {
    this.eInput.value = params.charPress;
  } else {
    if (params.value !== undefined && params.value !== null) {
      this.eInput.value = params.value;
    }
  }

  var that = this;
  this.eInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (!isKeyPressedNumeric(event)) {
      that.eInput.focus();
      if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    } else if (that.isKeyPressedNavigation(event)) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });

  // only start edit if key pressed is a number, not a letter
  var charPressIsNotANumber = params.charPress && ('1234567890'.indexOf(params.charPress) < 0);
  this.cancelBeforeStart = charPressIsNotANumber;
};

NumericCellEditor.prototype.isKeyPressedNavigation = function(event) {
  return event.keyCode === 39 ||
    event.keyCode === 37;
};


// gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
NumericCellEditor.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.eInput;
};

// focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
NumericCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
  this.eInput.focus();
};

// returns the new value after editing
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelBeforeStart = function() {
  return this.cancelBeforeStart;
};

// example - will reject the number if it contains the value 007
// - not very practical, but demonstrates the method.
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelAfterEnd = function() {
  var value = this.getValue();
  return value.indexOf('007') >= 0;
};

// returns the new value after editing
NumericCellEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
  return this.eInput.value;
};

// any cleanup we need to be done here
NumericCellEditor.prototype.destroy = function() {
  // but this example is simple, no cleanup, we could  even leave this method out as it's optional
};

// if true, then this editor will appear in a popup
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isPopup = function() {
  // and we could leave this method out also, false is the default
  return false;
};


function GenderCellRenderer() {}

GenderCellRenderer.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
  if (params.value !== "" || params.value !== undefined || params.value !== null) {
    var gender = '<img border="0" width="15" height="10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/' + params.value.toLowerCase() + '.png">';
    this.eGui.innerHTML = gender + ' ' + params.value;
  }
};

GenderCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.eGui;
};

function MoodCellRenderer() {}

MoodCellRenderer.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
  if (params.value !== "" || params.value !== undefined || params.value !== null) {
    var imgForMood = params.value === 'Happy' ? 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley.png' : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley-sad.png';
    this.eGui.innerHTML = '<img width="20px" src="' + imgForMood + '" />';
  }
};

MoodCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.eGui;
};

function MoodEditor() {
  this.defaultImgStyle = 'padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;  border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 4px;';
  this.selectedImgStyle = 'padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid lightgreen; padding: 4px;';
}

MoodEditor.prototype.onKeyDown = function(event) {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (key == 37 || // left
    key == 39) { // right
    this.toggleMood();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};

MoodEditor.prototype.toggleMood = function() {
  this.selectMood(this.mood === 'Happy' ? 'Sad' : 'Happy');
};

MoodEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.container = document.createElement('div');
  this.container.style = "border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid grey;background: #e6e6e6;padding: 15px; text-align:center;display:inline-block;outline:none";
  this.container.tabIndex = "0"; // to allow the div to capture keypresses

  this.happyImg = document.createElement('img');
  this.happyImg.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley.png';
  this.happyImg.style = this.defaultImgStyle;

  this.sadImg = document.createElement('img');
  this.sadImg.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley-sad.png';
  this.sadImg.style = this.defaultImgStyle;

  this.container.appendChild(this.happyImg);
  this.container.appendChild(this.sadImg);

  var that = this;
  this.happyImg.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    that.selectMood('Happy');
    params.stopEditing();
  });
  this.sadImg.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    that.selectMood('Sad');
    params.stopEditing();
  });
  this.container.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    that.onKeyDown(event)
  });

  this.selectMood(params.value);
};

MoodEditor.prototype.selectMood = function(mood) {
  this.mood = mood;
  this.happyImg.style = (mood === 'Happy') ? this.selectedImgStyle : this.defaultImgStyle;
  this.sadImg.style = (mood === 'Sad') ? this.selectedImgStyle : this.defaultImgStyle;
};

// gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
MoodEditor.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.container;
};

MoodEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
  this.container.focus();
};

MoodEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
  return this.mood;
};

// any cleanup we need to be done here
MoodEditor.prototype.destroy = function() {};

MoodEditor.prototype.isPopup = function() {
  return true;
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading


export default Example8;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { render } from 'react-dom'
  //  import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
    import 'ag-grid-enterprise'
    import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'

    import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css'
    import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css'
    import {DataGrid} from '@cib-jpm-ui-toolkit/data-grid'
    import $ from 'jquery'

    function cloneObject (obj) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
    }


    class InvoiceTextFields extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          columnDefs: [

                       {headerName: 'Field Name', field: 'fieldName', width: 70},
                       {headerName: 'Extracted Taxonomy', field: 'extractedTaxonomy', width: 70},
                       {headerName: 'Taxonomy Data Field', field: 'taxonomyDataField', width: 70},
        {
            headerName: 'Corrected Texonomy',
            field: 'value',
            width: 70,
            editable: true,
            cellEditorSelector:function (params) {
                if (params.data.type === 'age') {
 return {
                    component: 'numericCellEditor'
                }
}

                if (params.data.type === 'examination') {
return {
                    component: 'agSelectCellEditor',
                    params: { values: extractValues(carMappings) },
                    valueFormatter: function (params) {
                        return lookupValue(carMappings, params.value)
                      },
                      valueParser: function (params) {
                        return lookupKey(carMappings, params.newValue)
                      }
                }
}
                if (params.data.type === 'tenor') {
                    return {
                                        component: 'agSelectCellEditor',
                                        params: { values: extractValues(tenorMappings) },
                                        valueFormatter: function (params) {
                                            return lookupValue(carMappings, params.value)
                                          },
                                          valueParser: function (params) {
                                            return lookupKey(carMappings, params.newValue)
                                          }
                                    }
                    }

                if (params.data.type === 'dateVal') {
 return {
             cellEditor: 'datePicker'
                }
}

                return null
            }
        }
    ],
 //   components: { datePicker: getDatePicker() },
          rowData: [
        {value: '28/02/2019', type: 'dateVal', fieldName:'Expiry Date'},
        {value: 'YES', type: 'tenor', fieldName:'Tenor Type'},
        {value: 'Vessel 1', type: 'text', fieldName:'Vessel Name'},
        {value: 'Examine Document', type: 'examination', fieldName:'Examination Type'},

    ],
          gridOptions:{

              onRowEditingStarted: function (event) {
                  console.log('never called - not doing row editing')
              },
              onRowEditingStopped: function (event) {
                  console.log('never called - not doing row editing')
              },
              onCellEditingStarted: function (event) {
                  console.log('cellEditingStarted')
              },
              onCellEditingStopped: function (event) {
                  console.log('cellEditingStopped')
              }

          }
        }
      }

      onGridReady = params => {
        this.gridApi = params.api
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
      };

      onCellClicked = (event) => {
          console.log('hi: ' + event.colDef.field)
           console.log('hi type: ' + event.colDef.type)
           if (this.props.correctedTaxonomy === null) {
               console.log('null')
           }
          if (this.props.correctedTaxonomy === '') {
              console.log('empty')
          }
         if (event.colDef.field === 'value' && this.props.correctedTaxonomy !== null) {
             var rowModel = this.gridApi.getModel()
              var rowNode = rowModel.rowsToDisplay[event.rowIndex]
             event.data.correctedText = this.props.correctedTaxonomy
             rowNode.setDataValue('value', event.data.correctedText)
     }
     };


      render () {
        return (
                <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>

            <div
              id='myGrid'
              style={{
                height: '100%',
                width: '103%'
              }}
              className='ag-theme-balham'
            >
              <DataGrid
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
   //             components={this.state.components}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}
              gridOptions={this.state.gridOptions}
                onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
              onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }


    var carMappings = {
            'Examine Document': 'Examine Document',
            'Do not Examine': 'Do not Examine',
            'Send on approval with Doc Exam': 'Send on approval with Doc Exam',
            'Send on Approval Without Doc' : 'Send on Approval Without Doc ',
            'Exam' : 'Exam'
    }
    var tenorMappings = {
      'YES': 'YES',
      'NO': 'NO'

    }
    function extractValues (mappings) {
      return Object.keys(mappings)
    }
    function lookupValue (mappings, key) {
      return mappings[key]
    }
    function lookupKey (mappings, name) {
      for (var key in mappings) {
        if (mappings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (name === mappings[key]) {
            return key
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function getCharCodeFromEvent (event) {
        event = event || window.event
        return (typeof event.which === 'undefined') ? event.keyCode : event.which
    }

    function isCharNumeric (charStr) {
        return !!/\d/.test(charStr)
    }

    function isKeyPressedNumeric (event) {
        var charCode = getCharCodeFromEvent(event)
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode)
        return isCharNumeric(charStr)
    }


    function getDatePicker () {
        console.log('in gerDatePicker...')
          function Datepicker () {}
          Datepicker.prototype.init = function (params) {
            this.eInput = document.createElement('input')
            this.eInput.value = params.value
            $(this.eInput).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.getGui = function () {
            return this.eInput
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
            this.eInput.focus()
            this.eInput.select()
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.getValue = function () {
            return this.eInput.value
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.destroy = function () {}
          Datepicker.prototype.isPopup = function () {
            return false
          }
          return Datepicker
        }



    export default InvoiceTextFields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
    import $ from 'jquery'

    function cloneObject (obj) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
    }


    class InvoiceTextFields extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          columnDefs: [

                       {headerName: 'Field Name', field: 'fieldName', width: 70},
                       {headerName: 'Extracted Taxonomy', field: 'extractedTaxonomy', width: 70},
                       {headerName: 'Taxonomy Data Field', field: 'taxonomyDataField', width: 70},
        {
            headerName: 'Corrected Texonomy',
            field: 'value',
            width: 70,
            editable: true,
            cellEditorSelector:function (params) {
                if (params.data.type === 'age') {
 return {
                    component: 'numericCellEditor'
                }
}

                if (params.data.type === 'examination') {
return {
                    component: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
                    params: { values: extractValues(carMappings) },
                    valueFormatter: function (params) {
                        return lookupValue(carMappings, params.value)
                      },
                      valueParser: function (params) {
                        return lookupKey(carMappings, params.newValue)
                      }
                }
}
                if (params.data.type === 'tenor') {
                    return {
                                        component: 'agSelectCellEditor',
                                        params: { values: extractValues(tenorMappings) },
                                        valueFormatter: function (params) {
                                            return lookupValue(carMappings, params.value)
                                          },
                                          valueParser: function (params) {
                                            return lookupKey(carMappings, params.newValue)
                                          }
                                    }
                    }

                if (params.data.type === 'dateVal') {
 return {
             cellEditor: 'datePicker'
                }
}

                return null
            }
        }
    ],
 //   components: { datePicker: getDatePicker() },
          rowData: [
        {value: '28/02/2019', type: 'dateVal', fieldName:'Expiry Date'},
        {value: 'YES', type: 'tenor', fieldName:'Tenor Type'},
        {value: 'Vessel 1', type: 'text', fieldName:'Vessel Name'},
        {value: 'Examine Document', type: 'examination', fieldName:'Examination Type'},

    ],
          gridOptions:{

              onRowEditingStarted: function (event) {
                  console.log('never called - not doing row editing')
              },
              onRowEditingStopped: function (event) {
                  console.log('never called - not doing row editing')
              },
              onCellEditingStarted: function (event) {
                  console.log('cellEditingStarted')
              },
              onCellEditingStopped: function (event) {
                  console.log('cellEditingStopped')
              }

          }
        }
      }

      onGridReady = params => {
        this.gridApi = params.api
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
      };

      onCellClicked = (event) => {
          console.log('hi: ' + event.colDef.field)
           console.log('hi type: ' + event.colDef.type)
           if (this.props.correctedTaxonomy === null) {
               console.log('null')
           }
          if (this.props.correctedTaxonomy === '') {
              console.log('empty')
          }
         if (event.colDef.field === 'value' && this.props.correctedTaxonomy !== null) {
             var rowModel = this.gridApi.getModel()
              var rowNode = rowModel.rowsToDisplay[event.rowIndex]
             event.data.correctedText = this.props.correctedTaxonomy
             rowNode.setDataValue('value', event.data.correctedText)
     }
     };


      render () {
        return (
                <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>

            <div
              id='myGrid'
              style={{
                height: '100%',
                width: '103%'
              }}
              className='ag-theme-balham'
            >
              <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
   //             components={this.state.components}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}
              gridOptions={this.state.gridOptions}
                onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
        //      onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }


    var carMappings = {
            'Examine Document': 'Examine Document',
            'Do not Examine': 'Do not Examine',
            'Send on approval with Doc Exam': 'Send on approval with Doc Exam',
            'Send on Approval Without Doc' : 'Send on Approval Without Doc ',
            'Exam' : 'Exam'
    }
    var tenorMappings = {
      'YES': 'YES',
      'NO': 'NO'

    }
    function extractValues (mappings) {
      return Object.keys(mappings)
    }
    function lookupValue (mappings, key) {
      return mappings[key]
    }
    function lookupKey (mappings, name) {
      for (var key in mappings) {
        if (mappings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (name === mappings[key]) {
            return key
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function getCharCodeFromEvent (event) {
        event = event || window.event
        return (typeof event.which === 'undefined') ? event.keyCode : event.which
    }

    function isCharNumeric (charStr) {
        return !!/\d/.test(charStr)
    }

    function isKeyPressedNumeric (event) {
        var charCode = getCharCodeFromEvent(event)
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode)
        return isCharNumeric(charStr)
    }


    function getDatePicker () {
        console.log('in gerDatePicker...')
          function Datepicker () {}
          Datepicker.prototype.init = function (params) {
            this.eInput = document.createElement('input')
            this.eInput.value = params.value
            $(this.eInput).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.getGui = function () {
            return this.eInput
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
            this.eInput.focus()
            this.eInput.select()
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.getValue = function () {
            return this.eInput.value
          }
          Datepicker.prototype.destroy = function () {}
          Datepicker.prototype.isPopup = function () {
            return false
          }
          return Datepicker
        }



    export default InvoiceTextFields
```